# Azure keyVaultEndpoint return null while trying migration to Azure SQL Database with Update-Database -Migration command

Tags: azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-keyvault, ef-core-3.1

I've set-up an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project with EF Core, which is running fine in my Development environment (Visual Studio 2019 Community, Version 16.10.3). For my databases I've saved the connection strings in `secrets.json` and everything was fine.

I'm starting now to deploy my project for production.
I've moved the secrets to Azure Key Vault and set it up with `Connected services` according to Microsoft's documentation [Add Key Vault to your web application by using Visual Studio Connected Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/vs-key-vault-add-connected-service).

In my `Program.cs` file I now have the code to get my `keyVaultEndpoint`.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("mykeyvault"));
                
                config.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

My `launchSettings.json` file is:

```
{
    "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54964",
      "sslPort": 44331
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "mykeyvault": "https://<mykeyvault>.vault.azure.net/",
        "uriString": "https://<mykeyvault>.vault.azure.net/",
        "AZURE_USERNAME": "myAzureUsername",
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Vivace": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "mykeyvault": "https://<mykeyvault>.vault.azure.net/",
        "uriString": "https://<mykeyvault>.vault.azure.net/",
        "AZURE_USERNAME": "myAzureUsername",
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

I then moved the databases connection strings to Azure.
I configured the web app to connect to Key Vault and created and assign a managed identity:

```
az webapp identity assign --name "<my-webapp-name>" --resource-group "myResourceGroup"
```

To give my web app permission to do get and list operations on my key vault, I passed the principalId to the Azure CLI az keyvault set-policy command:

```
az keyvault set-policy --name "<mykeyvault>" --object-id "<principalId>" --secret-permissions get list
```

If I start debugging `F5` my webapp and set a breakpoint in my `Program.cs` file at `var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("mykeyvault"));` I get access to my secrets stored in Azure Key Vault. Everything works fine.

I've tried then to migrate a database to Azure SQL from the `Package Manager Console` with the command:

```
Update-Database -Migration VivaceVereinUsers -Context ApplicationDbContext -Verbose
```

I've added `-Verbose` to understand better what was going on.

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
    Using project 'Vivace'.
Using startup project 'Vivace'.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe exec --depsfile "C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\VivaceFreiburg\Vivace\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Vivace.deps.json" --additionalprobingpath C:\Users\MARCO\.nuget\packages --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages" --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet" --additionalprobingpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder" --runtimeconfig "C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\VivaceFreiburg\Vivace\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Vivace.runtimeconfig.json" C:\Users\MARCO\.nuget\packages\microsoft.entityframeworkcore.tools\3.1.13\tools\netcoreapp2.0\any\ef.dll database update VivaceVereinUsers --context ApplicationDbContext --verbose --no-color --prefix-output --assembly "C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\VivaceFreiburg\Vivace\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Vivace.dll" --startup-assembly "C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\VivaceFreiburg\Vivace\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Vivace.dll" --project-dir "C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\VivaceFreiburg\Vivace\\" --language C# --working-dir "C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\VivaceFreiburg" --root-namespace Vivace
Using assembly 'Vivace'.
Using startup assembly 'Vivace'.
Using application base 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\VivaceFreiburg\Vivace\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1'.
Using working directory 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\VivaceFreiburg\Vivace'.
Using root namespace 'Vivace'.
Using project directory 'C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\VivaceFreiburg\Vivace\'.
Finding DbContext classes...
Finding IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementations...
Finding application service provider...
Finding Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting service provider...
Using environment 'Development'.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at Vivace.Program.<>c.<CreateHostBuilder>b__1_0(HostBuilderContext context, IConfigurationBuilder config) in C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\VivaceFreiburg\Vivace\Program.cs:line 24
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'uriString')
No application service provider was found.
Finding DbContext classes in the project...
Found DbContext 'ApplicationDbContext'.
Found DbContext 'FilippaLibraryContext'.
Found DbContext 'VivaceCoursesContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
 ---> System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type 'Vivace.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtorSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions, Boolean fillCache)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_3.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass13_3.<FindContextTypes>b__13()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
```

Program.cs:line 24 is the following code line:

```
var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("mykeyvault"));
```

In the error I read also that `Parameter 'uriString'`is null, but this is wrong.
Il the `launchSettings.json` the `uriString` has been set correctly. Please refer to the attached code above.

The only way I've found to migrate my database to Azure SQL is to replace the code line

```
var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("mykeyvault"));
```

with:

```
var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri("https://<mykeyvault>.vault.azure.net/");
```

It seems that for some reasons, while running `Update-Database -Migration` from the `Package Manager Console` prevents accessing `EnvironmentVariable`.

I've also crossed-check if the deployment was done.
I can see the database with all tables (still empty) using the `SQL Server Object Explorer` in VS 2019.
I've deployed the project to `http://myproject.azurewebsites.net` and navigated to the page showing the database items. The page was empty, but I did not get any error.

Any idea about the error?
I have a workaround, but it is far away from best practice. I don't want to comment and uncomment lines of code to migrate my databases to Azure. It must just work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The launchSettings.json is specific to the local development machine and is not deployed when you build and publish. Hence your code is not able retrieve the value "mykeyvault".

The recommended way is to move the configuration to appsettings.json so that it is included in the build and published when you deploy your application.

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "mykeyvault": "https://<mykeyvault>.vault.azure.net/"
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
    {
        private static IConfigurationRoot _configuration;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
            {
                _configuration = config.Build();
                var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(_configuration["mykeyvault"]);
                config.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

You can set the value of mykeyvault based on the environment you are deploying to from your DevOps pipeline.